# Making parallel async await calls in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

Currently each of the value is set after setting the previous value, the async calls are not executed in parrallel. How do I make these calls execute in parallel?

```js
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [roll, setRollNo] = useState(1);
  const [sem, setSemester] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMyValue();
  }, []);

  const getMyValue = async () => {
    try {
      setIndex(JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@branch')) || 0);
      setSemester(JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@sem')) || 1);
      setRollNo(JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem('@roll')) || 1);
    } catch (e) {
      //  console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all`

```js
const [index, semester, roll] = await Promise.all([
AsyncStorage.getItem('@branch'),
AsyncStorage.getItem('@sem'),
AsyncStorage.getItem('@roll')]);

setIndex(JSON.parse(index) || 0);
setSemester(JSON.parse(semester) || 1);
setRollNo(JSON.parse(roll) || 1);
```

Or if you like to turn such thing into mapping monstrosity as recommended in the answers there you go...

```js
const params = ['@branch', '@sem', '@roll'];
const defaultValues = [0, 1, 1];

const [index, semester, roll] = await Promise.all(
  params.map(AsyncStorage.getItem))
  .then((values) => values.map((pr, index) => JSON.parse(pr) || defaultValues[index]));

setIndex(index);
setSemester(semester);
setRollNo(roll);
```

Answer (score 3):

To execute several promises in parallel you need organize them as array and execute unsing Promise.all:

```
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const [roll, setRollNo] = useState(1);
  const [sem, setSemester] = useState(1);

  useEffect(() => {
    getMyValue();
  }, []);

  const getMyValue = async () => {
    try {
      const itemsArr = ['@branch', '@sem', '@roll']
      const result = await Promise.all(promisesArr.map(item => AsyncStorage.getItem(item)))
      setIndex(JSON.parse(result[0]) || 0);
      setSemester(JSON.parse(result[1]) || 1);
      setRollNo(JSON.parse(result[2]) || 1);
    } catch (e) {
      //  console.log(e);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2):

React JS does not batch the state updates if the event handler is async.
In your example, as you are await-ing on `AsyncStorage.getItem`, they are not batched.

You can @Józef 's solution to batch them up

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14259#issuecomment-450118131

Answer (score 1):

Using `for await of ...`

We use an array of jobs to getItem, then after `await`, we can set the state of each item based on its type.

@Jozef's answer is also a great option as well, very good use of array deconstruction there

```
const response = []

const jobs = ["@branch", "@sem", "@roll"]

for await (item of jobs) {
  const res = await AsyncStorage.getItem(item);
  response.push({
    type: item, 
    res
  })
}

/**
 response 
 [ 
  { type: "@branch", res: <res> }, 
  { type: "@sem", res: <res> }, 
  { type: "@roll", res: <res> }] 
*/ 


response.forEach(item => {
  const { type, res } = item;
  if (type === "@branch") {
    setIndex(JSON.parse(res))
  } else if (type === "@semester") {
    setSemester(JSON.parse(res))
  } else if (type === "@roll") {
    setRollNo(JSON.parse(res))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need a async await here as you don't want to wait just use a promise instead

```
const getMyValue2 = () => {
    try {
      Promise.all([
        Promise.resolve( AsyncStorage.getItem('@branch')),
        Promise.resolve( AsyncStorage.getItem('@sem')),
        Promise.resolve( AsyncStorage.getItem('@roll'))
      ]).then(data => {
        setIndex(JSON.parse(data[0] || 0));
        setRollNo(JSON.parse(data[1] || 1));
        setSemester(JSON.parse(data[2] || 1));
      });
    } catch (e) {
      //  console.log(e);
    }
  };
```